# Need advice on adding Auth provider in production app - Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I launched an app a week ago which has a couple hundred users now. The only authentication provider I used was gmail and my database structure looked like this:

```
- AllUsersInfo:
   - $userEmail                     // example: "blah@gmail.com"
       - "uid": $userUID            // example: "1234567890"
       - "name": $userDisplayName   // example: "John Doe"

- AllUsersData
   - $userUID                       // example: "1234567890"
       - "userData": { ... }
```

Basically, I made one node (`AllUsersInfo`) to just hold users' emails as the key and that user's uid and name as the value. The other node (`AllUsersData`) actually contains each user's data that they generate in the application as the value, with the key being their uid. I separated these two nodes because the top one is lightweight and good for searching, while the bottom one is extra secure and has more data.

**The issue:**

Now I'm adding Facebook authentication and am struggling to see how I can keep the integrity of my database's structure. The problem is that if someone signed in with gmail previously and is now signing up with facebook, their facebook account's email could be the same as the gmail they signed up with previously. This would cause an overlap in the `AllUsersInfo` node since keys have to be unique in Firebase.

I'm struggling to figure out how I can deal with these overlapping cases. If I overwrite an email's previous data in the `AllUsersInfo` node with the new name and uid it would render the old user's authentication unsearchable. If I change the structure of the `AllUsersInfo` to allow for multiple uid's and names it would cause some backwards compatibility issues.

Can anybody please help me find a good solution to this potential database structure refactoring?

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution to this problem, as well as another issue which is Facebook users might not even have an email (they made their account using a phone number) is the following:

After authenticating user through facebook (or gmail), check if their email is already in the database or if there is no email (phone number situation), in which case show them a screen asking them to type in an email to use with this new account.

Not the best solution, but it fixes both issues.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, your app has only hundred's of users. I advice you to use Firebase UI library which handles all these problems and all you need is to write 3-5 lines of code.

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) is the link to the Firebase UI Android library. Add it to your project and connect your app to Firebase by following [these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) steps.

Once done, enable Google and Facebook Login from Firebase Console, follow the steps and then add these lines to your app.

```
startActivityForResult(
AuthUI.getInstance()
    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
    .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()
                                ))
    .build(),
RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Now all the test cases are handled by Firebase and you can sit back and relax.

Comment: How about being a little more specific